# How can I input the list of words in a loop that can be added to the url to get the results

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am giving the url as input :  url = "https://www.amazon.in/s?k=headphones&page=1"
This works fine but stops at page 19
Instead of we breaking at page 19, I want to give the next input as "https://www.amazon.in/s?k=" +

1. "speakers&page=1"
2. "earbuds&page=1"
   and so on to run in a loop

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import requests
```

````
data =[]

def getdata (url):
    header = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' } 
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=header)
    amazon_html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    a_soup = soup(amazon_html,'html.parser')
    
    for e in a_soup.select('div[data-component-type="s-search-result"]'):
        try:
            title = e.find('h2').text
        except:
            title = None
            
        data.append({
            'title':title
        })
        
    return a_soup

def getnextpage(a_soup):
  page= a_soup.find('a',attrs={"class": 's-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-button s-pagination-separator'})
  page = page['href']
  url =  'http://www.amazon.in'+ str(page)
  return url
            
while True:
  geturl = getdata(url)
  url = getnextpage(geturl)
    
  if not url:
    break
  print(url)```


```output = pd.DataFrame(data)
output
````

This code is returning the correct results, but instead of me giving a new url every time I want it to input a list of items which can be added at the end of the url one at a time to fetch the results which can be added to the DataFrame
Note: The search results stop at 19th page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list for your keywords, iterate it and include the while loop into each iteration.

```
keywords = ['speakers','earbuds']

for k in keywords:
    url = 'https://www.amazon.in/s?k='+k
    while True:
        geturl = getdata(url)
        url = getnextpage(geturl)

        if not url:
            break
        print(url)
```

*Be aware that amazon does not like such automated access to its pages and recognises the patterns of access quite quickly. To reduce the frequency of the requests a bit, you should at least include some delay `time.sleep()`. Of course, it would be even better to use an official api.*

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib

data =[]

def getdata (url):
    header = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' } 
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=header)
    amazon_html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    a_soup = soup(amazon_html,'html.parser')
    
    for e in a_soup.select('div[data-component-type="s-search-result"]'):
        try:
            title = e.find('h2').text
        except:
            title = None
            
        data.append({
            'title':title,
            'url':'http://www.amazon.in' + e.h2.a['href']
        })
        
    return a_soup

def getnextpage(a_soup):
    try:
        page = a_soup.find('a',attrs={"class": 's-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-button s-pagination-separator'})['href']
        url =  'http://www.amazon.in'+ str(page)
    except:
        url = None
    return url


keywords = ['speakers','earbuds']

for k in keywords:
    url = 'https://www.amazon.in/s?k='+k
    while True:
        geturl = getdata(url)
        url = getnextpage(geturl)

        if not url:
            break
        print(url)
```

##### Output (print)

```
http://www.amazon.in/s?k=speakers&page=2&qid=1649420352&ref=sr_pg_1
...
http://www.amazon.in/s?k=speakers&page=20&qid=1649420373&ref=sr_pg_19
http://www.amazon.in/s?k=earbuds&page=2&qid=1649420375&ref=sr_pg_1
...
http://www.amazon.in/s?k=earbuds&page=20&qid=1649420394&ref=sr_pg_19
```

##### Output (`pd.DataFrame(data)`)

|  | title | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Echo Dot (3rd Gen) - #1 smart speaker brand in India with Alexa (Black) | http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/electronics/15765862031/ref=sr_bs_0_15765862031_1 |
| 1 | TimbreSonic Rhythm Speaker Wired Karaoke Ultimate Sound Party Portable Speaker | http://www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A01688993VZM1IH2U6JB5&url=%2FTimbreSonic-Speaker-Karaoke-Ultimate-Portable%2Fdp%2FB096M2T346%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dspeakers%26qid%3D1649421227%26sr%3D8-2-spons%26psc%3D1%26smid%3DAK0P65LCJ5QQN&qualifier=1649421227&id=2899208110237385&widgetName=sp_atf |
| 2 | boAt Stone 180 5W Bluetooth Speaker with Upto 10 Hours Playback, 1.75" Driver, IPX7 and TWS Feature(Black) | http://www.amazon.in/boAt-Stone-Bluetooth-Speaker-Black/dp/B08JMC1988/ref=ice_ac_b_dpb?keywords=speakers&qid=1649421227&sr=8-3 |
| 3 | Speaker | http://www.amazon.in/Generic-Speaker/dp/B09X5M77MZ/ref=sr_1_omk_4?keywords=speakers&qid=1649421227&sr=8-4 |
| 4 | Zebronics Zeb-Warrior 2.0 Multimedia Speaker with Aux Connectivity,USB Powered and Volume Control | http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/computers/1375442031/ref=sr_bs_4_1375442031_1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 847 | Zebronics Zeb-Sound Bomb 5 TWS Earbuds with Bluetooth v5.0, up to 22H Backup, Flash Connect, Splash Proof, Voice Assistant, Touch Control, 10mm Driver, Built in Microphone and Type C(Black) | http://www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_mtf_aps_sr_pg20_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A09061362IHFGLF39FZ4K&url=%2FZebronics-Zeb-Sound-Bluetooth-Assistant-Microphone%2Fdp%2FB09NNNLBVD%2Fref%3Dsr_1_308_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dearbuds%26qid%3D1649420939%26sr%3D8-308-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1649420939&id=2014190349292195&widgetName=sp_mtf |
| 848 | boAt Airdopes 141 True Wireless Earbuds with 42H Playtime, Beast Mode(Low Latency Upto 80ms) for Gaming, ENx Tech, ASAP Charge, IWP, IPX4 Water Resistance, Smooth Touch Controls(Bold Black) | http://www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_mtf_aps_sr_pg20_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A08646093S9SKZXE3VDX4&url=%2FboAt-Airdopes-141-Wireless-Resistance%2Fdp%2FB09N3ZNHTY%2Fref%3Dsr_1_309_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dearbuds%26qid%3D1649420939%26sr%3D8-309-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1649420939&id=2014190349292195&widgetName=sp_mtf |
| 849 | Skyfly Xbot GE100 Wired in Ear Earphones with Mic (Black) | http://www.amazon.in/Skyfly-Xbot-Gaming-Earphones-Detachable/dp/B07ZYR78B3/ref=sr_1_310?keywords=earbuds&qid=1649420939&sr=8-310 |
| 850 | JBL C115 TWS, True Wireless Earbuds with Mic, Jumbo 21 Hours Playtime with Quick Charge, True Bass, Dual Connect, Bluetooth 5.0, Type C & Voice Assistant Support for Mobile Phones (Black) | http://www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_btf_aps_sr_pg20_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A0791293Y8WP49FN4EZU&url=%2FJBL-Wireless-Bluetooth-Assistance-Integration%2Fdp%2FB08L5ZC8R3%2Fref%3Dsr_1_311_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dearbuds%26qid%3D1649420939%26smid%3DA14CZOWI0VEHLG%26sr%3D8-311-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1649420939&id=2014190349292195&widgetName=sp_btf |
| 851 | Crossbeats Airpop Bluetooth Truly Wireless In Ear Earbuds With Mic, with 30Hrs Playtime Ultralight Bluetooth Earphone with Mic & Voice Assistant, Passive Noise Cancelling Headset, Type-C Fasting Charging - Blue | http://www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_btf_aps_sr_pg20_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A10368023R9B7RAUU82SP&url=%2FCrossbeats-Bluetooth-Ultralight-Assistant-Cancelling%2Fdp%2FB09PDSVQTW%2Fref%3Dsr_1_312_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dearbuds%26qid%3D1649420939%26sr%3D8-312-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1649420939&id=2014190349292195&widgetName=sp_btf |

Comment: This is fetching the results of only speakers and not earbuds. How can I get the earbuds results once it reaches the 19 page of speakers.

Comment: It's still not working in a loop

Comment: *not working* - The specification is a bit vague, could you perhaps elaborate a bit more so that I can reproduce it. That would be great.